# Как правильно пишется название города в Панаме?

Tags: орфография

В сети соседствуют 2 варианта: Портобело и Портобелло.

- [Портобело | ru.wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE)
- [Портобелло | sardtravel.ru](http://www.sardtravel.ru/countries/panama/cities/portobelo)
- [Достопримечательности Портобелло | journeying.ru](http://journeying.ru/dostoprimechatelnosti-portobello-chto-posmotret-i-kuda-schodit-v-portobello.html)

Answer (score 3):

Название этого города в оригинале San Felipe de Portobelo, поэтому причин для удвоения "л" здесь нет. Путаница возможна из-за района Портобелло (Portobello) в Дублине, а также некоторых других англоязычных топонимов,  где как раз удвоенные согласные.